# Wrap method in other method with different name to make code more readable - Good or Bad?

Tags: c#

I'm working with [Anonymous Pipes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-anonymous-pipes-for-local-interprocess-communication) to be able to communicate between 2 applications. I have 3 classes. A base class `Node` which holds the incoming and outgoing streams and methods like `Read` and `Write`. Deriving from this class are `Client` and `Server`. They each initialize respectively their `AnonymousPipeClientStream` and `AnonymousPipeServerStream` and have a method to sync with each other.

Having above code allows me to communicate between the 2 applications. I start the "server" application. This application starts the "client".

When both applications are started I need to send some arguments from the server to the client. The client is basically waiting for messages from the server. On the server I need to start the reading of the arguments on the client, then send the arguments and end the reading on the client so it's free to start another task. To do this I simply need to

1. write the start command,
2. write the arguments,
3. write the end command and
4. wait for the client to confirm the task is finished.

```
public void ServerStartClientTask()
{
    Write(ReadInputs); // (1)
    Write(Arg1); // (2)
    Write(Arg2); // (2)
    Write(ReadInputs); // (3)
    while (WaitFor(ReadInputs)); // (4)
}
```

This is "straightforward" when you're the writer of the code (in my opinion) and is the convention how communication with the client has to happen. I wanted to make it more clear for myself and my colleagues so I came up with the following:

```
public void StartClientTask(Flag flag)
{
    Write(flag);
}

public void EndClientTask(Flag flag)
{
    Write(flag);
    while (WaitFor(flag)) { }
}

public void ServerStartClientTask()
{
    StartClientTask(ReadInputs); // (1)
    Write(Arg1); // (2)
    Write(Arg2); // (2)
    EndClientTask(ReadInputs); // (3) and (4)
}
```

This code merely wraps code into another method to make it more readable how the communication is dome with the client.

Now for the question.
This example is not limiting to my question but just the use case I have now and to introduce my question. Is doing this wrapping of code with just other names a good or bad practice? Both examples work perfectly fine, they're just written differently. Is there a benefit to doing the 2nd approuch or would you rather just write a comment at (1), (3) and (4) in the 1st example?

Comment: Unfortunately, "best practice" questions like this are off topic for stack overflow because they generate opinion-based answers.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion this is a very good practice and I use it all the time.
Makes the code very readable for other developers.

this way I rarely have to use comments **inside** my methods because the names of the methods explain what is happening.